# How to fill PDF form in php

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, pdf

I have many PDF forms, I would need to fill them each in php with the data I already have.

Here is just a [sample PDF form](http://thewebjockeys.com/TheWebJockeys/Fillable_PDF_Sample_from_TheWebJockeys_vC5.pdf)  , I want to fill this form using php. The data I already have in DB. I just want to fill this form and save it.

I am working in PHP Zend Framework.

All I want is when I would download those forms from my site, it would pre-fill all the fields in the pdf form with the information I already have.

Please help me.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Calling [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) is a nice way to accomplish this. I'll assume that you know how to [execute an external program](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and leave that out.

First, create an [FDF](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html) file from your PDF.

```
pdftk form.pdf generate_fdf output data.fdf
```

You can now use that as template. The sample that you provided looks like this:

```
%FDF-1.2
%<E2><E3><CF><D3>
1 0 obj 
<<
/FDF 
<<
/Fields [
<<
/V ()
/T (Date)
>> 
<<
/V /
/T (CheckBox2)
>> 
<<
/V /
/T (CheckBox3)
>> 
<<
/V /
/T (CheckBox4)
>> 
<<
/V /
/T (CheckBox5)
>> 
<<
/V ()
/T (Your_Last_Name)
>> 
<<
/V ()
/T (Your_First_Name)
>> 
<<
/V /
/T (CheckBox1)
>>]
>>
>>
endobj 
trailer

<<
/Root 1 0 R
>>
%%EOF
```

The fields are lines that start with `/V ()`. Enter your desired values into those fields. For example:

```
%FDF-1.2
%<E2><E3><CF><D3>
1 0 obj 
<<
/FDF 
<<
/Fields [
<<
/V (February 4, 2012)
/T (Date)
...
```

Finally, merge the FDF with the PDF. Execute the command:

```
pdftk form.pdf fill_form data.fdf output form_with_data.pdf
```

If you don't need to keep the FDF and generated PDF files, you can simply pipe the data via stdin and stdout instead of using temp files.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I would need a little more from you, Is PDFTK something should be installed on server ?? I didn't work with PDF much, is there some example, or could you explain a bit more that how could I execute external program?? Please help me out.

Comment: Yes, install pdftk on the server. You can find the [instructions here](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk/). To execute system commands from PHP simply call the exec function. For example. `<?php exec('/usr/bin/pdftk form.pdf fill_form data.fdf output form_with_data.pdf'); ?>`

Comment: Thanx Richard, I will try. Thanks a million.

Comment: @RichardAyotte This was a good find :) I have to do the exact same thing, with a twist. I need also to include an image in one of the form fields. How would I do that?

Comment: I haven't done images but found this thread which explains it. http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1156035. I don't have time to update answer at the moment.

Comment: **CAUTION** if you're generating your FDF from scratch, don't forget to escape parentheses `(`, `)`, and backslashes `\\` from your inputs. there are a lot of PHP libraries that handle it for you like this one https://github.com/admonkey/php-fdf

Comment: Could you give a example for piping the `.pdf ` _and_ the `.fdf`?
So far I use `passthru('pdftk file.pdf fill_form file.xdfd output - flatten');`, and would like to get rid of both files on disk.

Comment: To "tick" a checkbox in FDF format use `/V /Yes`

Comment: In the outputted file, will those filled in fields still be editable/interactive fields? Or will they be converted to plain text-elements? If they are still interactive, is there any way of converting to static?

Comment: it fails at handling unicode chars like arabic or hebrew

Answer (score 19):

I found this and it works for me. It is an unofficial patch for Zend to fill FDF Form Fields.[Site with the discussion and patch](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-141)

NO INSTALLATION, NO OUTSIDE PROGRAMS, NO COORDINATES

Use:

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('input-file-containing-form.pdf');
$pdf->setTextField('name', 'Someone');
$pdf->setTextField('address', '1 Main Street');
$pdf->setTextField('city', 'Cyberspace');
$pdf->save('outputfile.pdf');
```

If page no longer exists here is the patch for PDF.php (if someone have problems - write me privete message):

```
--- Pdf.php.orig    2009-11-15 17:52:57.000000000 +0100
+++ Pdf.php 2010-01-07 04:05:23.000000000 +0100
@@ -202,6 +202,13 @@
      * @var array
      */
     protected static $_inheritableAttributes = array('Resources', 'MediaBox', 'CropBox', 'Rotate');
+    
+    /**
+     * List of form fields
+     *
+     * @var array - Associative array, key: name of form field, value: Zend_Pdf_Element
+     */
+    protected $_formFields = array();

     /**
      * Request used memory manager
@@ -315,6 +322,7 @@

             $this->_loadNamedDestinations($this->_trailer->Root, $this->_parser->getPDFVersion());
             $this->_loadOutlines($this->_trailer->Root);
+            $this->_loadFormfields($this->_trailer->Root);

             if ($this->_trailer->Info !== null) {
                 $this->properties = $this->_trailer->Info->toPhp();
@@ -557,6 +565,61 @@
             $this->_originalOpenOutlinesCount = $root->Outlines->Count->value;
         }
     }
+    
+    /**
+     * Load form fields
+     * Populates the _formFields array, for later lookup of fields by name
+     *
+     * @param Zend_Pdf_Element_Reference $root Document catalog entry
+     */
+    protected function _loadFormFields(Zend_Pdf_Element_Reference $root)
+    {
+      if ($root->AcroForm === null || $root->AcroForm->Fields === null) {
+        return;
+      }
+      
+      foreach ($root->AcroForm->Fields->items as $field)
+      {
+          if ( $field->FT->value == 'Tx' && $field->T !== null ) /* We only support fields that are textfields and have a name */
+          {
+              $this->_formFields[$field->T->value] = $field;
+          }
+      }
+      
+      if ( !$root->AcroForm->NeedAppearances || !$root->AcroForm->NeedAppearances->value )
+      {
+        /* Ask the .pdf viewer to generate its own appearance data, so we do not have to */
+        $root->AcroForm->add(new Zend_Pdf_Element_Name('NeedAppearances'), new Zend_Pdf_Element_Boolean(true) );
+        $root->AcroForm->touch();
+      }
+    }
+    
+    /**
+     * Retrieves a list with the names of the AcroForm textfields in the PDF
+     *
+     * @return array of strings
+     */
+    public function getTextFieldNames()
+    {
+      return array_keys($this->_formFields);
+    }
+    
+    /**
+     * Sets the value of an AcroForm text field
+     *
+     * @param string $name Name of textfield
+     * @param string $value Value
+     * @throws Zend_Pdf_Exception if the textfield does not exist in the pdf
+     */
+    public function setTextField($name, $value)
+    {
+      if ( !isset($this->_formFields[$name]))
+        throw new Zend_Pdf_Exception("Field '$name' does not exist or is not a textfield");
+      
+      $field = $this->_formFields[$name];
+      $field->add(new Zend_Pdf_Element_Name('V'), new Zend_Pdf_Element_String($value) );
+      $field->touch();      
+    }

     /**
      * Orginize pages to tha pages tree structure.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much better than installing extra software. I can't quite believe that this patch NEVER made it into Zend Framework though.

Comment: I've just downloaded the Zend Framework and the patch is already in there... So no need to patch now.

Comment: @GonzaloBrusco Was it in the full package or just the Zend PDF library from github? I was hoping to use just zend pdf for a project but it looks like there are so many zend dependencies, it's almost useless on its own. Definitely none of this code in there at all from what I can see.

Comment: @Jestep - I just found it here: https://github.com/zf1/zend-pdf and it's happily working out of the box, with the patch already in the code. Very easy to install just it and the 4 required Zend dependencies using Composer - run `composer require zf1/zend-pdf` and add `require_once '<path to Composer's vendor dir>/autoload.php';` to the file where you need to use the PDF functionality.

Answer (score 14):

I found fpdf library looking for the same on internet.

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php

Code looks clean, easy to use and remember it, and works for pdf with forms (fillable).

```
<?php

/***************************
  Sample using a PHP array
****************************/

require('fpdm.php');

$fields = array(
    'name'    => 'My name',
    'address' => 'My address',
    'city'    => 'My city',
    'phone'   => 'My phone number'
);

$pdf = new FPDM('template.pdf');
$pdf->Load($fields, false); // second parameter: false if field values are in ISO-8859-1, true if UTF-8
$pdf->Merge();
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

It comes with example that worked out of the box.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I even used it to just JOIN pdf's pages using  from_template function and being able to print 150 pages of documents intead 150 files of 1 page. Some systems doesn't let you select 150 files then print them. The last time i saw that in ie: Windows i noticed that i was only capable to pick up to 15 ... weird. I was using a macro recorder to print them all, but finally joining them with fpdf was much more efficient, clean and less prone to errors. Regards.

Comment: It does not support xfa/xdp, which is the form format currently used by Adobe.

Comment: Project seems dead, however, should be OK if there's no PDF min version requeriment on the project: Create the form in a supported version with your form-creating tool and it should be okey. I'm gona try it.

Comment: Confirm this works. As explained in the website, if your PDF is a newer version, just do a `pdftk modele.pdf output modele2.pdf` and it will work.

Comment: Someone took the project and now is being updated here: https://github.com/codeshell/fpdm

Comment: @cesAR Fpdm allows you fillable forms, but is not a replacement of fpdf and will not expose all features of pdf (Cell, etc). It will work only for pdf with forms. To use templates with fpdf you'll need fpdi. I found newer versions of fpdi unusable, so in my projects in still using the old version.

Comment: it doesn't support `ObjStm` Object streams in pdfs which is quite common

Answer (score 2):

The [Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html)-component can draw text in your pdf, but it is a bit clumsy as you have to specify the x- and y-coordinates on your pdf-page. Something like that:

```
// This is the pdf-file you want to fill out...
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('/path/to/pdf-template.pdf')
$page = $pdf->pages[0]; // Use first page
$page->drawText("firstname lastname", 200, 600);
...
$pdf->pages[0] = $page;
// be sure to write to a new file, not the original empty  form.
$pdf->save('/path/to/pdf-output.pdf');
```

I don't know if there are easy ways to find the exact coords, I usually play around until it fits.

Comment: But this is not filling the PDF form, this would diffidently work for flat PDFs but now for fallible PDF forms.

Comment: I know, should have mentioned that. But as far as I know, this is the only way you can put text into a pdf using Zend_Pdf.