# ZendPdf - setTextField Cyrillic Characters Encoding

Tags: php, encoding, pdf-generation

I have applied this solution:

[How to fill PDF form in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139787/how-to-fill-pdf-form-in-php)

by Peter Denev. Now I have been struggling with the encoding of the text to fill in.

Basically, I read the text from a Post Parameter and the text is cyrillic. No matter what I have tried to change (I tried to change encodings in Pdf.php of ZendFramework by copying some functions and applying it to setTextField etc.) nothing works. This is my code:

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('reklam.pdf');
$pdf->setTextField("Text1", "Тест Инпут");
$pdf->setTextField("Text2", "Тест Инпут");
$pdf->setTextField("Text3", "Тест Инпут");
$pdf->save('outputfile.pdf');
```

The text in the outputfile is not human.

This is the modified Pdf.php: http://pastebin.com/q7YqNcb9

What to do? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your font includes the required characters. Obviously only the font settings set in the Acrobat form field properties are considered for form fields, that means it it is independent from the font you set in Zend.
2. If yes: This helped me:

   ```
   public function setTextField($name, $value)
   {
   if (!isset($this->_formFields[$name])) {
       throw new Zend_Pdf_Exception(
           "Field '$name' does not exist or is not a textfield"
       );
   }

   /** @var Zend_Pdf_Element $field */
   $field = $this->_formFields[$name];
   $field->add(
       new Zend_Pdf_Element_Name('V'), 
   // you must set $font to one of the Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font objects
       new Zend_Pdf_Element_String($font->encodeString($value, 'UTF-8'))
   );
   $field->touch();
   }
   ```